# Cycle2 slideshow with carousel pager not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, jquery-cycle2

The pager is built using the "Advanced Custom Template" on a carousel slideshow.

Boths slideshows look ok until I click the pager, then it acts strange: active slide doesn't change position; when clicking an item on the pager, doesn't show correct slide in main slideshow then stops working altogether.

See it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Shmfv/1/

```
    <div class="boxGaleria cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="> div" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href='#' ><img src='{{children.0.src}}'><h3>{{children.1.textContent}}</h2><h3>{{children.2.textContent}}</h2></a>" data-cycle-pager=".boxNav">
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>              
        <div>...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxNav cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-timeout="1500" data-cycle-fx="carousel" data-cycle-carousel-visible="3" data-allow-wrap="true" data-cycle-carousel-fluid="true" data-cycle-slides="> a"></div>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out a workaround... Can't use the plugin's pager option and had to add some scripting.

// fill the pager

```
$('.boxGaleria > div').clone().appendTo('.boxNav');
```

// update active slide in both slideshows

```
var slideshows = $('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-update-view',function(event, opts) {
    slideshows.not(this).cycle('goto', opts.currSlide);
});
```

// add click to the carousel/pager, correct slide index because the carousel adds a few duplicate children before and after to display correctly

```
$('.boxNav div').click(function(){
    var index = $('.boxNav').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(this);
    var todos = $('.boxGaleria').data('cycle.opts').slideCount;
    slideshows.cycle('goto', (index-todos));
});
```

Comment: came to a similar conclusion but found that it fails with wrap around on the carousel, (ie the duplicated items that cycle creates wont change the slider) - so does this actually work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

hey Check out this Q&A here

[jQuery Cycle2 - Carousel pager navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119783/jquery-cycle2-carousel-pager-navigation/21135086#21135086)

had issues with a similar method to yours.