# jQuery Cycle2 - Carousel pager navigation

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-cycle2

I'm using Cycle2's Carousel pager, very similar setup to the [example here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caro-pager.php).

My problem is that the previous and next sliders work fine, but clicking on the carousel won't change the slide in the other slider. It's working in the Cycle2 example linked above.

Check the JS in the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yCCLL/1/

The CSS in the example is broken but it doesn't matter, you can see what the problem is. If you click next it cycles but clicking on the images in the carousel doesn't change the slider.

I always get the error message in the console:

```
[cycle2] goto: invalid slide index
```

Comment: If you look at the DOM modifications the carousel makes, you'll see that your slideshow contains three copies of the original set of images, throwing off your numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I noticed that, the developer of cycle2 has stated that carousels create 3 times as many slides as actually exist. So how can I link them together with these extra slides being created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this in two ways (almost....)

1. by adding `data-cycle-allow-wrap="false"` to the carousel pager container. this seems to be full proof now,
2. I started getting a result with an infinite pager by changing the standard jQuery from the demo page

   ```
     var slideshows = $('#gallbig');

     var adjust = slideshows.children('img').length;

     $('#no-template-pager .cycle-slide').click(function(){
         var index = $('#no-template-pager').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(this);
         slideshows.cycle('goto', index - adjust);
     });
   ```

but that fails once it wraps around, as I don't need this features I've gone with option one, but this may get you started if you're after an infinite carousel.

NB my first fix that I'm now using has the same jQuery snippet withouth the adjust var.

Comment: I'm going to mark number 1 as the answer. Thanks for that. I thought I had actually tried that but I must have had something else wrong. Nice job!

Comment: Cool, I've seen a couple people struggle with this  - a lot of the time because they leave out the -cycle-  in the data attribute.

Answer (score 5):

I realise I'm a little late to the party but thought I'd share my own solution which works with `data-cycle-allow-wrap` set to `true`

There are 2 problems here. The first is when `data-cycle-allow-wrap` is set to `true` the duplicated slides never go through the `.click()` callback function

Secondly, as mentioned by Blazemonger the duplication throws off the indexing for each slide

**The Solution**

First off I set an "index" data attribute on each slide in my markup like below. When the plugin duplicates the slides it takes the data attribute along with it

```
<?php 
    $i = 0; 
    foreach($images as $image) { 
        echo '<img class="cycle-slide" data-index="' . $i . '" src="' . $image . '" />';
        $i++;

    } 
?>
```

Then in the JavaScript rather than using the `.click()` method I used `.on()` taking advantage of [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and got the index from the data attribute instead of what is returned from the plugin:

```
$('#cycle2').on('click', '.cycle-slide', function(){
    $('#cycle1').cycle('goto', $(this).data('index'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, wonderful solution to both carousel pager and infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this after struggling with my own carousel pager, so here's what I did, hope it helps someone out there: (some code taken from the pager carousel example on the Cycle2 site)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Cycle2 Slider:
    var slideshows = $('.cycle-slideshow');//selects both slideshows
    slideshows.on('cycle-next cycle-prev', function(e, opts) {
        // advance the other slideshow
        slideshows.not(this).cycle('goto', opts.currSlide);
    });

    $('.carousel .cycle-slide').click(function(){
        var index = $('.carousel').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(this);
        var slide_count = $('.carousel').data("cycle.opts").slideCount;

        // subtract the slide amount until the slide count is within bounds:
        while(index > slide_count) {
            index = index - slide_count;
        }
        slideshows.cycle('goto', index);
    });

});
```